# I need help identifying a connector. Its fiber supposedly

Tags: cable, fiber, modem, connector

I want to install a modem in my house instead of the ISP router that does everything horribly, but I can't identify which connector this is.

[image: Connector]

[image: Connector sideways]

[image]

Comment: Looks optic to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your images are of poor quality and lacking anything that could be used for comparing the scale of the connector. It would be much easier for you to perform a Google image search for `fiber connector types` and compare the images with what you have.

- [101 Series: Know Your Fiber Connectors](https://www.flukenetworks.com/blog/cabling-chronicles/101-series-know-your-fiber-connectors)
- Shaun Trezise: [Fiber Connectors - what's the difference?](https://www.ppc-online.com/blog/fiber-connectors-whats-the-difference)

It sure looks like a **SC/APC connector** (IEC 61754-4, *Subscriber Connector*, *Standard Connector*), where the green color indicates [Angled Physical Contact](https://www.fiberoptics4sale.com/blogs/archive-posts/95041478-what-are-apc-angled-physical-contact-fiber-connectors).

[image: SC connector]

Comment: Note that the green color indicates an **APC** type (*angled* physical contact) which cannot be mixed with PC/SPC/UPC.

Comment: Thanks, @Zac67; I've added this to the answer.